# Differences in Queue methods

Tags: java, methods, data-structures, queue, fifo

Why `Queue` have two different methods each for retrieving element and for removing element?

Retrieving methods: `element()` and `Element peak()`
Removing methods: `Element poll()` and `Element remove()`

What is difference between them (except return-type differences in first case)?

Comment: RTFM: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really read the JavaDoc for [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html):

[**`remove()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#remove()):

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue. *This method differs from **poll** only in that it throws an exception if this queue is empty.*

[**`element()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#element()):

> Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of this queue. *This method differs from **peek** only in that it throws an exception if this queue is empty.*

(Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0):

according to javadoc:

```
               Throws exception     Returns special value
Insert         add(e)               offer(e)
Remove         remove()             poll()
```

and special value here means:

> Returns:
>       true if the element was added to this queue, else false

The point is that queue can have predefined maximum length and if you try to insert to it when it's empty you can use add and get Exception or offer and get false returned (or might be empty and you want to remove an element)